# Google Sheets filter based on two lists

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I have the following situation:
I have three sets of data, let's say a set of names, a type of clothing and its colour.
I have one table which links a name to an article of clothing and I have another table which links a colour to an article of clothing.
What I want to do is count how many pieces of clothing one person has that have a particular colour.
I think I either have to find all the clothes one person has and then check for each of those which one are available in the desired colour, *or* I need to start by checking which clothes are available in that colour and then check if the person has any of those, but I don't know how to work with a list of results in Google Sheets.
Is there a way I can achieve this?

```
TABLE 1                TABLE 2
Name:     Type:    |   Colour:   Type:
John      Jeans    |   Blue      Shirt
John      Shorts   |   Blue      Jeans
John      Socks    |   Blue      Socks
Geralt    Shoes    |   Red       Socks
Geralt    Shirt    |   Red       Shirt
Stephanie Socks    |   Red       Shoes
Stephanie Jeans    |   Green     Jeans
                   |   Green     Shoes
```

In this example, if the person I'm looking at is John and the colour I'm looking at is blue, we can see that John has jeans, shorts and socks. Blue items include a shirt, jeans and socks. Jeans and socks appear in both of these lists, so the result should be jeans and socks (which means the eventual result I'm looking for is 2, since the list is 2 items long).

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: You are right, I made the example but I forgot to include it, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

**Use this formula** or [***Make a copy***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lgAE5XTqFgddSllauk7CN5-q2YjGk-AwXuRhw5mWypU/copy) of this example.

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(FILTER($B$3:$B,$A$3:$A=H2),
          MATCH(FILTER($B$3:$B,$A$3:$A=H2), 
                FILTER($E$3:$E,$D$3:$D=H3), false)), "No match"))
```

[image]

### Demo

[image]

### Update - handling "No match"

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(FILTER($B$3:$B,$A$3:$A=H2),
         MATCH(FILTER($B$3:$B,$A$3:$A=H2), 
               FILTER($E$3:$E,$D$3:$D=H3), false))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked, when I figured out it used commas instead of semicolons. One issue though, is that it shows a result of 1 when there is no match, what causes this? No match should mean the result is 0.

Comment: Update: Removing the value_if_error resolved the issue.

Comment: Should be good now test the update, removing error handling create other problems instead I replaced it with `IFNA`